# Install old AMD driver with obsolete dependencies

Tags: drivers, apt, laptop, amd-graphics, fglrx

I am trying to install an old AMD driver for my laptop on Kubuntu (Ubuntu 20.10 - groovy), but I get "following packages have unmet dependencies" issues for `libqtcore4` and `lib32gcc1`.

#### Details

I have downloaded the deb files from [the official AMD website](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/amd-radeon-hd-7000m-series/amd-radeon-hd-7490m), and I have written this script to install them.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install dkms
sudo apt-get install ./fglrx-core_15.201-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_14.01.deb ./fglrx_15.201-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_14.01.deb ./fglrx-dev_15.201-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_14.01.deb ./fglrx-amdcccle_15.201-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_14.01.deb
```

However, I get these errors:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib32gcc1 : Depends: gcc-10-base (= 10.2.0-5ubuntu1~20.04) but 10.2.0-13ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
...
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 fglrx : Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta2) but it is not installable
 fglrx-core : Depends: lib32gcc1 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I install these dependencies? Is there an unofficial package that allows me to do this?

My graphic card is a dual Radeon HD 6400M/7400M series + Intel HD 3000. Currently, the Intel graphic card is chosen using Mesa drivers, but I want to switch to AMD. I am OK with any unofficial driver that works.

Comment: No. My packages are not broken. The dependencies of this driver are obsolete. These are different issues.

Comment: The up-to-date AMD graphics driver is installed in Ubuntu by default, but you are trying. to install obsolete packages to replace the up-to-date preinstalled packages, so you are getting an appropriate error message about broken packages. Installing this obsolete package in your system would result in broken packages. Do you want to install it anyway?

Comment: My laptop is a dual graphic one, and the Intel graphics is being used by default. I want to switch to AMD graphics. fglrx (AMD's supported graphic) seems to promise to fix the issue. Is there any other way to switch to AMD graphic?